# How to send headers using Postclient library in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, http-post, windows-phone-7.1

I am sending post parameters in Windows Phone app using [PostClient](http://postclient.codeplex.com/) library. I want to add some headers to URL. How to do this?

Comment: Do you mean http://postclient.codeplex.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

As I see you can't do that directly via library. You should download [source code](http://postclient.codeplex.com/downloads/get/240328) and add this functionality by self.

It's pretty easy, because library is very small. They use [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to send the data and this class have a property - [Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.headers%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It's just a collection of name/value pairs. Add a collection into the class, add methods to access this collection and process this collection(add the headers from it) before the library sends requests.

Comment: Can u give a link to a more clear example for HttpWebrequest?

Comment: [reading headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.headers(v=vs.110).aspx), [working with](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6554/How-to-use-HttpWebRequest-and-HttpWebResponse-in-N), [sending data via post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.110).aspx), [exact POST use](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9ed17340-e0f7-4933-b06e-b4ccefca1391/httpwebrequest-post)...